# How do I prevent recurrence Strings?

Tags: java, string

I've defines a function printWordsOccurence(String str).
it's job to print How many times is each word repeated in this text :

**Text**: I am happy. I am a doctor. I like chocolate.

the expected results :

1. [3] I
2. [2] am
3. [1] happy.
4. [1] a
5. [1] doctor.
6. [1] like
7. [1] chocolate.

---

Here is my code :

```
 public static void printWordsOccurence(String str) {

    String[] words = str.split(" ");
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
            if (words[i].equals(words[j])) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter + " " + words[i]);
        counter=0;
    }
}
```

I can't prevent strings from repeating.
Any suggestions or hint would be very helpful

Comment: I recommend using the [`stream` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). If we wish to not use the `stream` API, I recommend using a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) (e.g. [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html)) for word counting.

Comment: @user16320675  Why all the code in a comment (which , BTW, is frowned upon by SO)?  You could have structured this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to not process words you have already seen. So when the `outer loop` sees a `familiar` one it needs to skip it.

The easiest way do do this would be to use a set or a map.  But there is another alternative using most of your existing code.

- simply replace the word when it is encountered with some string.
- then if that string is encountered again by the outer loop, ignore it.

```
public static void printWordsOccurence(String str) {
    
    String[] words = str.split(" ");
    // the marker which replaces the word when found.
    String seen = "#";

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        
        // if the word equals the marker, continue continue on
        // to the next word in this loop
        if (words[i].equals(seen)) {
            continue;
        }

        int counter = 0;

        // save the word since it may change when found
        String find = words[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
            if (find.equals(words[j])) {
                // replace the word with the substitute
                words[j] = seen;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(counter + " " + find);
    }
}
```

prints

```
3 I
2 am
1 happy.
1 a
1 doctor.
1 like
1 chocolate.
```

You may want to modify the words to eliminate any lingering punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the message within the outer loop and it will get executed for each of the words! Please try to use Map. Here I don't use the stream. Just used Java 7 way.
`

```
public static void printWordsOccurence(String str) {

        String[] words = str.split(" ");

        Map<String, Integer> res = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (String w : words) {
            if (res.containsKey(w)) {
                res.put(w, res.get(w) + 1);
            } else {
                res.put(w, 1);
            }
        }

        for (String w: res.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("[" + res.get(w) + "]" + w);
        }
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void printWordOccurance(String sentence) {
    Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();
    Arrays.stream(sentence.split("\\s+")).forEach(word -> countMap.compute(word, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1));
        
    System.out.println(countMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void printWordsOccurence(String str) {
    Arrays.stream(str.split("[\\s.]+"))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
            LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().forEach(e ->
            System.out.println("[" + e.getValue() + "] " + e.getKey()));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "I am happy. I am a doctor. I like chocolate.";
    printWordsOccurence(str);
}
```

output:

```
[3] I
[2] am
[1] happy
[1] a
[1] doctor
[1] like
[1] chocolate
```

Or

```
public static void printWordsOccurence(String str) {
    Map<String, Integer> counter = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String word : str.split("[\\s.]+"))
        counter.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
    for (Entry<String, Integer> e : counter.entrySet())
        System.out.println("[" + e.getValue() + "] " + e.getKey());
}
```